# Set two price book prices equal to each other

Tags: automation, pricebook, pricebookentry

Our company has two price books. The standard price book, and an intercompany price book. For the time being, we would like the prices on the intercompany price book to equal those on the standard price book.  Is there a way to mass update the prices on the intercompany book to equal the prices of the standard price book?

We have 1500 prices to update, so we’re trying to find a solution that doesn’t involve manually changing every price.

Comment: Yes - choose your automation technique and implement it. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_whichtool

Answer (score 0):

If you would like it to be a one-time job, not a periodic one - I'd say that this is more a data migration problem.

What you could do is:

1. Export records to the CSV file via [the Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/data_loader.htm) or any other data extraction tool (I'm especially a fan of the quick and easy to use [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh)). [Some SOQL basics could be beneficial here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql).
2. Make the necessary changes in MS Excel, Libre Office or any other tool that supports editing CSVs.
3. [Update the data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/inserting_updating_or_deleting_data.htm) via the Data Loader or any other data upload tool that works fine with Salesforce (I again prefer SF inspector here for smaller chunks of data).

If you would like to keep the sync between these price books all the time, [I'd go with the trailhead module suggested by identigral](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_whichtool). You would learn how to automate this task in your system properly.